# How to label a specific range of values in R?

Tags: r

## Data

My original data frame contains information on lane changes by different drivers. Each driver changes lanes multiple times. I created a column `lane.change` that contains `yes` at the point where vehicle lane changes. Following is a sample data frame that contains 2 lane changes for a single driver:

```
x <- structure(list(file.ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), class = "factor", .Label = "Car1"), frames = 1:11, 
    lane.change = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("no", "yes"), class = "factor"), 
    y.m = c(80, 80, 80, 81, 82, 82, 82, 83, 84, 84, 84)), row.names = c(NA, 
-11L), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("file.ID", "frames", 
"lane.change", "y.m"))
```

## Plot of lane changes:

[image]

The `LC1` and `LC2` lines show the range of lane changes in these data.

## What I want to do:

I want to label the range of values that are shown in the plot. This represents the complete duration of a lane change. So, my desired output is:

### Desired Output:

```
> x
   file.ID frames lane.change range_LC y.m
1     Car1      1          no        .  80
2     Car1      2          no        .  80
3     Car1      3          no      LC1  80
4     Car1      4         yes      LC1  81
5     Car1      5          no      LC1  82
6     Car1      6          no        .  82
7     Car1      7          no      LC2  82
8     Car1      8         yes      LC2  83
9     Car1      9          no      LC2  84
10    Car1     10          no        .  84
11    Car1     11          no        .  84
```

## What I tried and problems:

I know that I can refer to relevant `frames` using `x[which(x$lane.change=="yes"),"frames"]`. But the goal is to label previous and next rows for each lane change. I am stuck on how to do that. In addition, I want to apply it to all drivers (in the original data), each having different number of lane changes (>=2). Please guide me o what function to use. I prefer using `dplyr` and `purrr`. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First I'll make some helper functions

```
is_changing <- function(x) {
  x !=lag(x, default=first(x)) | x != lead(x, default=last(x))
}
```

This function basically looks to see if any particular value in a vector is next to a different value (increasing or decreasing).

The next function takes a vector of TRUE/FALSE values and assigns a new index to each run of TRUE values.

```
true_run_index <- function(x) {
  r<-rle(x)
  v<-r$values
  v[v] <- seq.int(sum(v))
  v[v==0]<-NA
  rep(v, r$length)
}
```

Then we can use those with your sample data

```
x %>% mutate(LC = true_run_index(is_changing(lane.change)))
x %>% mutate(LC = true_run_index(is_changing(y.m)))

#    file.ID frames lane.change y.m LC
# 1     Car1      1          no  80 NA
# 2     Car1      2          no  80 NA
# 3     Car1      3          no  80  1
# 4     Car1      4         yes  81  1
# 5     Car1      5          no  82  1
# 6     Car1      6          no  82 NA
# 7     Car1      7          no  82  2
# 8     Car1      8         yes  83  2
# 9     Car1      9          no  84  2
# 10    Car1     10          no  84 NA
# 11    Car1     11          no  84 NA
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. What if I want to label 2 or *any* number of rows before and after `lane.change=="yes"` row? I tried using `lag(x, 2, default=first(x))` but it does not correctly label the 2 rows after.

Comment: `lead()` and `lag()` are designed to pull out a single value. If you want to extract a larger collection around a value, then you'd probably have to write yet another helper function to do that for you. You might be able to use a version of the `embed` command but that makes working at the ends of the vector even more difficult. It's really a differently type of problem then the one you originally described.

Comment: you are right. Actually I figured out that for my original data I'd need to label 800 rows before and 800 rows after the `lane.change=="yes"` row. Can I edit this question?

Comment: That's different enough to justify opening a new question. You shouldn't meaningfully change a question after it's been answered.

Answer (score 1):

A solution using functions from `dplyr` and `data.table`. `x4` is the final output.

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

x2 <- x %>%
  mutate(LC_ID = rleid(lane.change)/2) %>%
  mutate(LC_ID2 = ifelse(LC_ID %% 1 == 0, paste0("LC", LC_ID), NA)) %>%
  mutate(LC_ID3 = lag(LC_ID2), LC_ID4 = lead(LC_ID2))

x3 <- mutate(x2, range_LC = coalesce(x2$LC_ID2, x2$LC_ID3, x2$LC_ID4, "."))

x4 <- x3 %>% select(file.ID, frames, lane.change, range_LC, y.m)
```

Comment: thanks for your solution. But as I mentioned in a comment to @MrFlick's answer, what if I want to label any number of rows before and after `lane.change=="yes"` row? In your solution, I changed argument `n` in `lead` and `lag` functions to 2. After that, I tried `x4 %>% tidyr::fill(range_LC, .direction = "down")` but it did nothing. Any suggestions?

Comment: I agree with @MrFlick. You are asking a new question. Consider having a new post.