# How to label any range of values around a specific row in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

This is a follow-up question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44828658/how-to-label-a-specific-range-of-values-in-r/44829027?noredirect=1#comment76643654_44829027).

## Data

```
x <- data.frame(file.ID = "Car1", 
                frames = 1:15, 
                lane.change = c("no", "no", "no", "yes", 
                                "no", "no", "no", "no", 
                                "no", "yes", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no"))
```

## Problem

I want to label *few* rows above and few rows after the `lane.change=="yes"` row in each lane change for a given `file.ID` group. The answers to previous question work for consecutive rows but not for any number of rows. I tried providing the argument `n` in `lead` and `lag` functions but it does not give desired results.

## Desired Output

Ideally, I want to be able to label any number of rows before and after `lane.change=="yes"`.In my original data frame I want to label 800 rows before and after. But in the sample data frame `x` I am trying to label 2. So the desired output should be:

```
   file.ID frames lane.change range_LC
1     Car1      1          no        .
2     Car1      2          no      LC1
3     Car1      3          no      LC1
4     Car1      4         yes      LC1
5     Car1      5          no      LC1
6     Car1      6          no      LC1
7     Car1      7          no        .
8     Car1      8          no      LC2
9     Car1      9          no      LC2
10    Car1     10         yes      LC2
11    Car1     11          no      LC2
12    Car1     12          no      LC2
13    Car1     13          no        .
14    Car1     14          no        .
15    Car1     15          no        .
```

Please help me get the desired output. Since the original data has multiple `file.ID`s, I prefer a `dplyr` solution because I can later use `group_by`. Thanks.

## EDIT

I want to generalize the code for multiple `file.ID`s. You can download the subset of original data frame that contains 2 `file.ID`s, [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByvW4Hq_6a56SWtta01Cb2tyNWs/view?usp=sharing). I tried following (thanks to @G5W's solution):

```
library(tidyr)
by_file.ID <- c %>% 
  group_by(file.ID) %>% 
  nest()

library(purrr)
by_file.ID <- by_file.ID %>% 
  mutate(range_LC = map(data, ~ ".")) %>% 
  mutate(Changes = map(data, ~ tail(which(.$lane.change=="yes"),-1)))
```

Please note that 1st lane change in each case is at a very small index number. So, I skip it by doing `tail(which(...), -1)`. Also, note that in these data I want to use 800 rows before and after lane change row. So, the code for individual `file.ID`s should be something like this:

```
range_LC[t(outer(Changes, -800:800, '+'))] = rep(1:length(Changes), each=1601)
```

The line above is the main piece of code that I am not sure how to apply to the groups of `file.ID`s. I thought about using a `for loop` with `do.call()` but it is likely to be very slow due to a large number of lane changes and `file.ID`s.

Thanks for your time and effort in helping me.

Comment: How do you deal with the potential overlapping when you specified a large number? For example, if you specify x to be 3, will row 7 be `LC1` or `LC2`?

Comment: @ycw, this is not a problem in the original data frame because the lane changes always have a large number of rows in between. So, in this case 2 rows are fine.

Comment: use `lag` for this.

Comment: @Masoud, `lag` and `lead` hep in labeling the individual rows. you can see @ycw's answer in the linked question. But how to label the rows in between?I tried using `tidyr::fill()` but it doesn't produce the required results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After further thinking and testing, I think this solution could work for the OP. This is an improved solution from [mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44828658/how-to-label-a-specific-range-of-values-in-r/44829434#44829434) and Masoud's in this thread. It requires the `fill` function from the `tidyr` package to fill `NA` between the upper and lower bound of land change.

```
# Load packages
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)
```

I created a larger test case than the OP's. Now there are two `file.ID`. I do this to test if the grouping can work for more than one car.

```
# Create example data frames
x <- data.frame(file.ID = c(rep("Car1", 20), rep("Car2", 20)),
                frames = 1:40, 
                lane.change = c(rep(c("no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "yes", 
                                "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no",
                                "no", "yes", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no"), 2)))
```

The OP can set the number of lead and lap here. Here I used 3 as an example. Notice that it is the OP's responsibility to make sure these do not overlap.

```
# Set the lead and lag distance
Step <- 3

# Create LC_ID, uppber bound and lower bound of the lead lag difference
x2 <- x %>%
  group_by(file.ID) %>%
  mutate(LC_ID = rleid(lane.change)/2) %>%
  mutate(LC_ID2 = ifelse(LC_ID %% 1 == 0, paste0("LC", LC_ID), NA)) %>%
  mutate(LC_ID3 = lag(LC_ID2, Step), LC_ID4 = lead(LC_ID2, Step))
```

The `LC_groupID1` and `LC_groupID2` are for grouping to be able to use `fill`.

```
# Create groups based on LC_ID, Group the data and apply fill for two directions
x3 <- x2 %>%
  mutate(LC_groupID1 = ifelse(LC_ID %% 1 == 0, LC_ID + 0.5, LC_ID), 
         LC_groupID2 = ifelse(LC_ID %% 1 == 0, LC_ID - 0.5, LC_ID)) %>%
  group_by(file.ID, LC_groupID1) %>%
  # Fill one direction based on LC_ID4
  fill(LC_ID4, .direction = "down") %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  # Fill the other direction based on LC_ID3
  group_by(file.ID, LC_groupID2) %>%
  fill(LC_ID3, .direction = "up") %>%
  ungroup()

# Coalesce all the columns
x4 <- mutate(x3, range_LC = coalesce(x3$LC_ID2, x3$LC_ID3, x3$LC_ID4,"."))

# Select the columns
x5 <- x4 %>% select(file.ID, frames, lane.change, range_LC)
```

`x5` is the final output.

Answer (score 3):

This just requires careful indexing into the array.

```
x$range_LC = "."
Changes = which(x$lane.change == "yes")
x$range_LC[t(outer(Changes, -2:2, '+'))] = rep(1:length(Changes), each=5)
x
   file.ID frames lane.change range_LC
1     Car1      1          no        .
2     Car1      2          no        1
3     Car1      3          no        1
4     Car1      4         yes        1
5     Car1      5          no        1
6     Car1      6          no        1
7     Car1      7          no        .
8     Car1      8          no        2
9     Car1      9          no        2
10    Car1     10         yes        2
11    Car1     11          no        2
12    Car1     12          no        2
13    Car1     13          no        .
14    Car1     14          no        .
15    Car1     15          no        .
```

Comment: Thank you. However, there is a slight problem. I am not sure how I can use this code when `file.ID` is a grouping variable. I tried using `purrr` library after `by_file.ID <- x %>% 
  group_by(file.ID) %>% 
  nest()`. But creating the `range_LC` is still a challenge after doing: `by_file.ID %>% 
  mutate(range_LC = map(data, ~ ".")) %>% 
  mutate(Changes = map(data, ~ which(.$lane.change=="yes")))`. So, how can I generalize this code when there is more than 1 `file.ID`. Please note that I mentioned that `file.ID` is a grouping variable in the question under 'Problem' section.

Answer (score 3):

I am just posting this answer to let you know [@ycw's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44828658/how-to-label-a-specific-range-of-values-in-r/44829434#44829434) is totally fine for this question as well. You just need to tweak it a little bit:

```
x22 <- x %>%
  mutate(LC_ID = rleid(lane.change)/2) %>%
  mutate(LC_ID2 = ifelse(LC_ID %% 1 == 0, paste0("LC", LC_ID), NA)) %>%
  mutate(LC_ID3 = lag(LC_ID2), LC_ID4 = lead(LC_ID2)) %>% 
  mutate(LC_ID5 = lag(LC_ID3), LC_ID6 = lead(LC_ID4))

x33 <- mutate(x22, range_LC = coalesce(x22$LC_ID2, x22$LC_ID3, x22$LC_ID4,
                                      x22$LC_ID5, x22$LC_ID6, "."))

x44 <- x33 %>% select(file.ID, frames, lane.change, range_LC)

#output:
x44

#    file.ID frames lane.change range_LC 
# 1     Car1      1          no        . 
# 2     Car1      2          no      LC1 
# 3     Car1      3          no      LC1 
# 4     Car1      4         yes      LC1 
# 5     Car1      5          no      LC1 
# 6     Car1      6          no      LC1 
# 7     Car1      7          no        . 
# 8     Car1      8          no      LC2 
# 9     Car1      9          no      LC2 
# 10    Car1     10         yes      LC2 
# 11    Car1     11          no      LC2 
# 12    Car1     12          no      LC2 
# 13    Car1     13          no        . 
# 14    Car1     14          no        . 
# 15    Car1     15          no        .
```